# What is a Kernel function passed using capture syntax?

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to understand how Elixir's & Kernel. + / 2 function works, could someone explain with some usage example?I tried to understand the following function but it was not clear to me.

```
def multiple_three_five do
    1..999
    |> Enum.filter(fn(n) -> rem(n, 3) == 0 or rem(n, 5) == 0 end)
    |> Enum.reduce(&Kernel.+/2)
    |> IO.puts
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're in `IEx`, you can use the `h` callback to display the documentation for a module or a function among others. Give it a try, it's more than helpful!

i.e.:

```
iex(1)> h Kernel.+
# the documentation will be displayed here
```

There is not much to add beside what's already in the documentation. Basically, `Kernel.+/2` is used to add two numbers.

You can call the `Kernel.+/2` function like this:

```
1 + 1
```

Or like so if you feel more fancy:

```
Kernel.+(1, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks man, i am very new to the language and the syntax is still very strange to me. I will use this documentation that you suggested.

Regards

Comment: I strongly advise that you go through the Getting Started Guide: https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/introduction.html

It's fairly well written. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @ryanzidago's answer, the syntax `&<module>.<function>/<arity>` is to convert a named function into an anonymous function. Arity stands for the number of arguments the function can take. This feature is often called "capture" which I don't quite understand why such a name.

For example,

```
&String.to_integer/1
```

works the same as

```
fn str ->
  String.to_integer(str)
end
```

maybe a little bit faster.

```
&Kernel.+/2
```

works the same as

```
fn a, b ->
  Kernel.+(a, b)
end
```

or

```
fn a, b -> a + b end
```

By the way, if the named function (public or not) is in the current module, you can omit the `<module>.` part.